White patches on exporting band composite landsat 8 level2 image

I am using google earth engine and want to export landsat 8 (band- 2 to 7) composite but in earth engine image is clear but when i export and open image to arcgis its appear white patches there.
What is this and how can I get rid of from it images are attached?
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
    var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2); // Apply scaling for optical bands
    return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true);
}

function processYear(year) {
    var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 9, 1);
    var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 10, 31);

    var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(aoi)
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
    .map(applyScaleFactors)
    .select(['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7']);
    var medianImage = dataset.median().clip(aoi);
    return medianImage.set('year', year);
}
var years = [2014, 2020, 2024];
var results = years.map(function(year) {
    return processYear(year);
});

var medianCollection = ee.ImageCollection(results);

var visualization = {
    bands: ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'],
    min: 0.0,
    max: 0.3,
};

Map.centerObject(aoi, 10);

Map.addLayer(medianCollection.filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', 2014)).first(), visualization, 'Median 2014');
years.forEach(function(year) {
    var image = medianCollection.filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', year)).first();
    Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image.select(['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7']), // Export only the required bands
    description: 'Median_Landsat_' + year,
    folder: 'GEE_Exports',
    scale: 30, // Landsat resolution
    region: aoi.geometry(),
    maxPixels: 1e13
    });
});


You are not masking out the clouds. Perhaps the median in your 2014 composite happened to be cloud free, but not the yearly composite you looked at in ArcGIS. You can use the QA_PIXEL to determine which pixels are cloudy and mask them out. Here's an example how you can go about doing that:
function maskClouds(image) {
    var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL')
    var fill = bitwiseExtract(qa, 0)
    var dilatedCloud = bitwiseExtract(qa, 1)
    var cloudConfidence = bitwiseExtract(qa, 8, 9)
    var cloudShadowConfidence = bitwiseExtract(qa, 10, 11)
    var cirrusConfidence = bitwiseExtract(qa, 14, 15)
  
    var mask = fill.not()
      .and(dilatedCloud.not())
      .and(cloudConfidence.lte(1))
      .and(cloudShadowConfidence.lte(1))
      .and(cirrusConfidence.lte(1))
      
    return image.updateMask(mask)
}


function bitwiseExtract(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined)
    toBit = fromBit
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
  return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
}

...

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterBounds(aoi)
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
    .map(maskClouds) // Mask out the clouds in each image in the collection   
    .map(applyScaleFactors)
    .select(['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7']);
    var medianImage = dataset.median().clip(aoi);
    return medianImage.set('year', year);

https://code.earthengine.google.com/6f310e39c18fe3d2a765009512179faa
Look at the Bitmask for QA_PIXEL section in the EE catalog entry about the image collection. With that, you should understand the bitwiseExtract() arguments.
